# Loading TextureRegion with filter diff from that of texture it came from

Tags: libgdx, texture-atlas

I am using libgdx .
While packing my texture atlas I have set the filter for mag and min to Nearest . But for just one region I wish to draw it with linear filter . Is it possible to have different filters for texture region than that of texture atlas it came from.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [sampler objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object), if is it a solution that would suit you. Basically a sampler object is openGL object which can store these kinds of settings for later use(binding) in shaders. 
Example of usage: [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tutorial%2014.html) tutorial.